# Drawing curves with SFML gives wrong shapes

Tags: c++, sfml, curve

I'm currently experimenting with SFML. I want to draw complex shapes using math curves. The equation in a plotter (I use https://www.desmos.com/calculator) is fine. The list of point in a plotter (I use http://www.shodor.org/interactivate/activities/SimplePlot/) is fine. The result with SFML is displaying unwanted artifacts and filling is incorrect (see https://i50.servimg.com/u/f50/19/87/95/25/sfml11.png and https://i50.servimg.com/u/f50/19/87/95/25/sfml12.png).

I can't figure out why ? Is it the code ? The graphic card capacity ? Am I using SFML for a purpose it has not been designed for ? Bad juju ?

Any help appreciated,

MC

`g++ -std=c++11 ./k.cpp -o ./k -Wfatal-errors  -lsfml-graphics -lsfml-window -lsfml-system`

````
#include <iostream>
#include <random>
#include <string>
#include <math.h>
#include "SFML/Graphics.hpp"

using namespace std;

struct point
    {
    double x;
    double y;
    };

struct ellipse
    {
    int index;
    point centerPoint;
    double radiusX;
    double radiusY;

    sf::ConvexShape SFMLShape;

    double xOffset;
    double yOffset;

    sf::Text ellipseTitle;
    point textPosition;
    };

ellipse computeCurve(point centerPoint,double radiusX,double radiusY,double beta)
    {
    // Based on https://www.mathcurve.com/courbes2d.gb/croixdemalte/croixdemalte.shtml
    // This is a four parameters variant. 

    int numberOfPoints=400;

    ellipse aCurve;
    aCurve.SFMLShape.setPointCount(numberOfPoints);
    aCurve.centerPoint.x=centerPoint.x;
    aCurve.centerPoint.y=centerPoint.y;
    aCurve.radiusX=radiusX;
    aCurve.radiusY=radiusY;
    double alpha=2*M_PI/numberOfPoints;

    std::random_device randomDevice;
    std::mt19937 seed(randomDevice());

    float l=-2;
    float p=-0.6;
    float n=0.5;
    float k=-0.5;

    point point;

    for(unsigned short i=0;i<=numberOfPoints/2;i++)
        {
        point.x=radiusX*cos(l*alpha*i)*(p+cos(n*alpha*i)/2 -k)+centerPoint.x; 
        point.y=radiusX*sin(alpha*i)*(p+cos(n*alpha*i)/2)+centerPoint.y;
        aCurve.SFMLShape.setPoint(i,sf::Vector2f(point.x,point.y));
cout << "computeFish 1 point n°" << i << " " << point.x << " " << point.y << endl;
        };

    for(unsigned short i=0;i<=numberOfPoints/2;i++)
        {
        point.x=radiusX*cos(l*alpha*i)*(p+cos(n*alpha*i)/2 -k)+centerPoint.x; 
        point.y=-radiusX*sin(alpha*i)*(p+cos(n*alpha*i)/2)+centerPoint.y;
        aCurve.SFMLShape.setPoint(numberOfPoints-i,sf::Vector2f(point.x,point.y));
cout << "computeFish 2 point n°" << numberOfPoints-i << " " << point.x << " " << point.y << endl;
        };

    aCurve.SFMLShape.setOrigin(aCurve.centerPoint.x,aCurve.centerPoint.y);
    aCurve.SFMLShape.setPosition(aCurve.centerPoint.x,aCurve.centerPoint.y);

    aCurve.textPosition.x=aCurve.centerPoint.x;
    aCurve.textPosition.y=aCurve.centerPoint.y;

    return aCurve;
    }

int main()
    {

    const   unsigned short windowWidth = 800;
    const   unsigned short windowHeight = 800;
    sf::ContextSettings settings;
    settings.antialiasingLevel = 4;
    sf::RenderWindow window(sf::VideoMode(windowWidth, windowHeight), "Demo",sf::Style::Default); // Default / None // Fullscreen

    sf::Event myEvent;
    sf::Clock ellipseClock;

    bool stopped=false;
    point centerPoint;
    centerPoint.x=300;
    centerPoint.y=300;
    double radiusX=200;
    double radiusY=150;
    double beta=0;
    ellipse mt=computeCurve(centerPoint,radiusX,radiusY,beta);
    mt.SFMLShape.setOutlineColor(sf::Color::Red);
    mt.SFMLShape.setFillColor(sf::Color(40,40,40,127));
    mt.SFMLShape.setOutlineThickness(1.f);
    while (window.isOpen())
        {
        while (window.pollEvent(myEvent))
            {
            if (myEvent.type == sf::Event::EventType::Closed)
                {
                window.close();
                }
            }
        window.clear();
        if (ellipseClock.getElapsedTime().asMilliseconds() > 100.0f)
            {
            // 
            ellipseClock.restart();
            }
        window.draw(mt.SFMLShape);
        window.display();
        }
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
    }```
````

Answer (score 0):

You cannot draw concave shapes using `sf::ConvexShape`. More precisely:

> Although the name of `sf::ConvexShape` implies that it should only be used to represent convex shapes, its requirements are a little more relaxed. In fact, the only requirement that your shape must meet is that if you went ahead and drew lines from its center of gravity to all of its points, these lines must be drawn in the same order. You are not allowed to "jump behind a previous line". Internally, convex shapes are automatically constructed using triangle fans, so if your shape is representable by a triangle fan, you can use `sf::ConvexShape`. With this relaxed definition, you can draw stars using `sf::ConvexShape` for example.

A solution to this constrait is that you can make concave shapes from multiple convex one, but for your use case it's not viable. The only thing that you could do is to plot the individual points (maybe so much that it would seem continuous), but for this kind of work SFML is just not suited for.